# Ruby filter binary data

Tags: ruby, parsing, filter, rake, sphinx

I working on search in ms words files using sphinx xmlpipe and rake task for geting formated xml for him. That when i get problems. Basicly what i do is detect file type with MIME::Types.type_for and if this file doc or docx read it with catdoc or extract its word/document.xml, the problem is when task returns specific entries in xml, sphinx fails to index, he finishes with xml parse error:

```
XML parse error: not well-formed (invalid token)
```

When i look on what task returns i see that indexing broke on lines that looks like  binary data entries. 
What i can do filter binary data from text, or atleast detect documents with them so that sphinx could finish indexing?

Comment: Ok, it seems that nobody knows the answer. After googling for some period, i ended up using antiword instead of catdoc, he seems to understand and crop images from text. Also i give up using MIME::Types for unix "file" utility, as it gives more accurate results and dont depend from file extention

Answer (score 0):

After additional googling i at last found the solution.

```
string.scan(/.*?((?:[\t\n\r\x20-\x7E])+|(?:\xD0[\x90-\xBF])+|(?:\xD1[\x80-\x8F])+|).*?/);
```

This regexp will select only Standard ASCII symbols and Cyrillic multi-byte UTF-8 characters( Russian/Bulgarian ones). 
And this regexp:

```
/.*?((?:[\t\n\r\x20-\x7E])+|(?:\xD0[\x90-\xBF])+|(?:\xD1[\x80-\x8F])+|(?:\xC3[\x80-\xBF])+|).*?/
```

allows you to select additional dialect characters, e.g UTF-8 Latin letters with diaeresis, tilde? like: “ä”, “ö”, “ü”

Many thanks to this guy blog's: http://blog.famzah.net/2010/07/01/filter-a-character-sequence-leaving-only-valid-utf-8-characters/ where i found the answer <3 <3 <3